# Arrays in loops

Tags: python, arrays, histogram

Hi I have a question that I am not sure how to implement in python. 
I have three different arrays. I have values in X and values in Y. Such that to each X a specific Y belongs (X,Y). Now, from it I built a histogram.

```
U, V = histogram(X, bins=arange(min(X), max(X), 50))
```

The third array (V) has the number of points for each bin. Knowing this, I want to print the different Y values for each point in different bins. It is:

```
for i, j in zip(X, Y):
     if a<i<b:
         print j
```

where a is the first value in V and b the second one. For example in my first case, the first value is 500 and the second one 600, so it would be:

```
for i, j in zip(X, Y):
     if 500<i<600:
         print j
```

and here it prints the Y values for the points that lie in the range 500-600 in X. What now I would like to do is to implement a loop so I don't have to be writing manually the different entries for V. I was thinking about something like:

```
for i, j, k in zip(X,Y,range(len(V))):
     if V[k]<i<V[k+1]:
         print j
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: "Such that to each X a specific Y belongs (X,Y)" How?

Comment: I don't have time to give a full answer right now, but you're looking for `numpy.digitize`.  It will return indices for the bin that each `X` belongs in, and then you can use this to extract which `Y` values fall into each `X` bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in your question, it looks like you're using numpy. There are better ways to approach this problem in numpy, and I'll go over those at the end of the answer.  For the moment, though, let's look at why what you tried didn't work.

---

The reason that it's not working is that your `V` array is the bin edges.  It's not the same size as your `X` or `Y` arrays.

When you `zip` sequences together, `zip` stops when the shortest sequence has been iterated through.  For example:

```
for i, j in zip([1, 2], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]):
    print j
```

Will yield:

```
5
6
```

In your case, you actually want to iterate over the bins, and then have an inner loop over `X` an `Y`.  For example:

```
for k in range(len(V)):
     for i, j in zip(x, y):
         if V[k]<i<V[k+1]:
             print j
```

We could also make this a bit more readable by doing something like:

```
bin_edges = V

for left, right in zip(bin_edges, bin_edges[1:]):
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        if left < i < right:
            print j
```

However, this both of these are *horribly* inefficient in numpy.  (Iterating through numpy arrays is slower than iterating through lists, but this would be slow even with lists.)

Fortunately, you're using numpy, and there are *much* more efficient ways.

---

First, let's reproduce the example above, but let's use boolean indexing to remove the inner loop:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data
x, y = np.random.random((2, 100))

# Your "U" and "V" arrays, but I'm changing the names for clarity
counts, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=20)

# Rather than iterate over an index, let's use a slightly different trick
for left, right in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:]):
    # Use boolean indexing to replace the inner loop
    print y[(x > left) & (x < right)]
```

Another way to do this is through `numpy.digitize`:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some x, y data
x, y = np.random(2, 100)

# Create a histogram of x
counts, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=30)

# Return an series of indicies of which bin each x-value falls into
# This will be the same size as x and have values between 0 to len(bins)
idx = np.digitize(x, bins)

# Print the y-values for each bin
for i in range(bins.size):
   y[idx == i]
```

Either way, using boolean indexing for this instead of the inner loop will yield significant speedups.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the last tip. It makes things so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you're getting? You're probably indexing outside of the array in

```
for i, j, k in zip(X,Y,range(len(V))):
     if V[k]<i<V[k+1]:
         print j
```

When `k` is `len(V)` there is no `V[k+1]`. You can do something like

```
for i, j, k in zip(X,Y,range(len(V)-1)):
     if V[k]<i<V[k+1]:
         print j 
#handle the last bin separately
if X[-1] > V[-1]:
    print Y[-1]
```